# Wordpress template causing white/blank screens with source and navigation behind them on IE7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, wordpress-theming

I've bought and installed a custom template for Wordpress and it is randomly giving white/blank pages on all areas of the site excluding the admin cp when navigating around on IE7 (works fine on Chrome). I know it's the template as it works fine with standard templates, and I'm pretty sure it's a javascript as I've disabled all the plugins to see if it was those.

Here's the site: http://www.visualisebi.com

Looking at a page with minimal code that has the issue (Admin CP login area), the only major differences I can see that are different between the new template pages and a standard template are the amount of scripts the new template calls. Here's an example:

New template source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Visualise Business Intelligence Services &rsaquo; Log In</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-admin-css'  href='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.css?ver=20111208' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-fresh-css'  href='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.css?ver=20111206' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/modernizr-2.0.js?ver=2.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/superfish.js?ver=1.4.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/easyTooltip.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js?ver=1.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/jquery.loader.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-includes/js/swfobject.js?ver=2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/jquery.cycle.all.js?ver=2.99'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/audiojs/audio.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/themes/theme1334/js/custom.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
</head>
<body class="login">
<div id="login"><h1><a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress">Visualise Business Intelligence Services</a></h1>
<p class="message"> You are now logged out.<br />
</p>

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Password<br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90" /> Remember Me</label></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Log In" tabindex="100" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-admin/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    </p>
</form>

<p id="nav">
<a href="http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password?</a>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function wp_attempt_focus(){
setTimeout( function(){ try{
d = document.getElementById('user_login');
d.focus();
d.select();
} catch(e){}
}, 200);
}

if(typeof wpOnload=='function')wpOnload();
</script>

    <p id="backtoblog"><a href="http://www.visualisebi.com/" title="Are you lost?">&larr; Back to Visualise Business Intelligence Services</a></p>
    </div>


<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-pagenavi-css'  href='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi/pagenavi-css.css?ver=2.70' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpBannerizeJavascriptLocalization = {"ajaxURL":"http:\/\/www.visualisebi.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-bannerize/js/wpBannerizeFrontend.min.js?ver=3.0.32'></script>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Standard template source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Visualise Business Intelligence Services &rsaquo; Log In</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-admin-css'  href='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.css?ver=20111208' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-fresh-css'  href='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.css?ver=20111206' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
</head>
<body class="login">
<div id="login"><h1><a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress">Visualise Business Intelligence Services</a></h1>
<p class="message"> You are now logged out.<br />
</p>

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Password<br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90" /> Remember Me</label></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Log In" tabindex="100" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-admin/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    </p>
</form>

<p id="nav">
<a href="http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password?</a>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function wp_attempt_focus(){
setTimeout( function(){ try{
d = document.getElementById('user_login');
d.focus();
d.select();
} catch(e){}
}, 200);
}

if(typeof wpOnload=='function')wpOnload();
</script>

    <p id="backtoblog"><a href="http://www.visualisebi.com/" title="Are you lost?">&larr; Back to Visualise Business Intelligence Services</a></p>
    </div>


<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-pagenavi-css'  href='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi/pagenavi-css.css?ver=2.70' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpBannerizeJavascriptLocalization = {"ajaxURL":"http:\/\/www.visualisebi.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.visualisebi.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-bannerize/js/wpBannerizeFrontend.min.js?ver=3.0.32'></script>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the original theme properly working in IE7 ??

Have you checked the theme demo where you purchased the theme ? Is it working in IE7. If not you can ask the theme owner to fix the issue.

(Cannot comment yet and hence the answer.)